# Android change setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to dynamically set the contentView in my activity.
Because one time i use a xml as contentView, but at anothertime i use a custom view as contentView.

But how do i change the contentView?

I read about that the ViewFlipper can do this, but a viewFlipper is implemented in a xml file. And within this ViewFlipper you can add your different views.

But i dont know them at the beginning, so i cant write them all in my xml file.
Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?Can you better explain how you want the screens to be shown to the user?

Comment: For example a user calls a Activity called "Test", this Test exists of a View with RadioButtons, if the user is finished with the RadioButtons he can go on and should see now the view with Dragable Elements, after that RadioButtons or Dragable Elements again.. I want to switch the view technically... 
I dont think that it would be wise to create a new Activity for each View...

Comment: What Ted Hopp says is perfect.For your requirement i suggest that insead of switching views you can have all required layouts in a single XMLand just show/ hide individual layouts as required, ex:- Have two layouts for Radio Button and Draggable elements.Make the 2nd layout visible after Radiobutton is selected.Same logic for multiple views.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call `setContentView` at any time<sup>*</sup>, not just in `onCreate`. Just define all the views you want in separate XML files and pass the relevant id when it's time to switch. If you want to define the new layout dynamically in code, then do that and call `setContentView` and pass the root view of your new layout.

<sup>*</sup> Technically, you can call `setContentView` any time you are executing on the event thread. Otherwise you need to use a Handler to call it.

Comment: And if i call setContentView again, in which method do i jump? In onCreate again?

Comment: @krackmoe - I don't understand the question. You don't jump anywhere. The model is: some event happens (e.g., the user presses a button) that runs some code in your app. This code decides it is time to change layouts, so it calls `setContentView`. The framework takes care of updating the display. Your code then goes back to waiting for some new event to happen.